# The correct way to use struct

Tags: c, struct

I have:

```
char player_one[10];

printf("Enter name for first player:\n");
scanf("%s",player_one);

struct player
{
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];
enum colour col;
};
```

declared in my .h file, but when I try to create a new player in the .c file. ie -

```
player p1 {player_one, blue}
```

the compiler says error: unknown type name 'player'

Comment: In C (as opposed to C++) the key-word `struct` is part of the type's name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`struct` keyword required before `player`.

```
struct player p1 {...,...}
```

or you can use [typedef](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm) for avoiding `struct` keyword.

like

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];
    enum colour col;
}player;
```

and

```
player p1 {player_one, blue}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either put `struct` before like Jayesh answer, or use a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct player {...} player;
```